# Accessing GoogleApis.com from Silverlight - Is it possible?

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to access googleapis.com/youtube/v3 from Silverlight. I am getting a System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
I can see in Fiddler that I am getting a http 404 when the app tries to access the ClientAccessPolicy.xml file on the google site. Does this mean that googleapi can not be access from a WebClient class in Silverlight?

Thanks
Barry

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx

seems that access from Silverlight is not possible. Looks like the only way around this is to implement a WCF/Webservice on the same domain and call it from Silverlight. Not sure why Microsoft limit access from silverlight to Webservices when Windows, WCF and Webservices are not secured in this way (ClientAccessPolicy). Doesn't make much sense.